# busybox shell refuses to execute the particular line of script

Tags: shell, busybox

I am using busybox shell to execute a script which the bash executes when i boot linux using the nfs. Please let me know the correct alternative for this line.

```
cur_major=$((0x`stat -c %t $dev 2>/dev/null`))
```

The busybox throws in an error saying "0x" syntax error, which i understand is the problem with the syntax of this line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
major_hex=`stat -c %t $dev 2>/dev/null`
cur_major=`printf "%2d" 0x"$major_hex"`
```

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thanks for replying to this question.
In busybox I couldn't find the support for the bc command.
As all my drivers are character modules, so cannot do cat/proc/partitions for any info on them.
I need to find a way where I can have major number in decimal.
I am posting this comment 3rd time, as i dunno why it is not getting appended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a problem running it. 
try doing it step by step if all else fails.

```
$ var=$(stat -c "%t" $dev 2>/dev/null)
$ var=$((0x$var))
```

actually `$(())` lets you perform arithmetic. what is it actually you are trying to do? are you trying to convert to a hex number?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a very quick reply.
I have tried this also, but the busybox shell is unable to interpret the 0x. It still gives syntax error.

I am trying a load modules  using this script based on the output of this line. The script does some comparison on its output and does mknod. I am stuck here as there are around 50 insmod's to do and 50 mknod, which is very cumbersome if done manually.